# Entity Framework 5 and MySql in Visual Studio 2010 - Model First issue

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-5, mysql-connector, ef-model-first

I have application developed in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0, using MySql database.

I have installed Entity Framework 5.0 and EF 5.x DbContext Generator for VB (using NuGet), then MySql Connector 6.5.5. I'm using Model First approach, so I created two tables, then I chose "Generate database from model.." option. After setting connection provider and connection parameters (with successful test connection to database), I clicked "Finish", and *.sql file was generated but nothing was created in my database. Worse still, the generated SQL script is in SQL Server Flavour and it has a header:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Entity Designer DDL Script for SQL Server 2005, 2008, and Azure
-- --------------------------------------------------
-- Date Created: 03/22/2013 12:11:00
-- Generated from EDMX file: C:\Apps\app\DataAccessLayer\DbModel.edmx
-- --------------------------------------------------

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF;
GO
USE [MyDatabase];
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID(N'dbo') IS NULL EXECUTE(N'CREATE SCHEMA [dbo]');
GO

(...)
```

How to enforce EF with Mysql and MySql Connector to automatically create database tables, and to generate MySql script, no SQL Server script?

Best regards,
WP

Comment: I have changed "DDL Generation Template" to "SSDLToMySQL.tt (VS)", and the proper SQL script flavor is generated. But database was not created automatically. Maybe permissions - I will check...

Comment: Database is not generated automatically. You must execute the generated script yourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question comments give us and answer. Summary:

1) Change **DDL Generation Template** property of the *.edmx model to **SSDLToMySQL.tt (VS)**

2) Database is not generated automatically. You must execute the generated script yourselves (In Visual Studio in Server Explorer view, or using other tools, i.e PhpMyAdmin).